# How to make jQuery Mobile not manipulate the hash when displaying a dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a jQuery Mobile + backbone site. To play nice with backbone, I've also disabled routing like so:

```js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;     });
```

I'd like to display a dialog via js in my jQM + backbone site:

```js
 $.mobile.changePage("#dialog",
        {
            transition: 'pop',
            role: 'dialog', 
            changeHash:false
        });
```

The problem is, this fires a hash change event. My page router picks this up and routes to an incorrect page, away from the dialog.

Why does a simple changePage with a dialog ignore the changeHash parameter? Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Did you find n answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite an old thread - but the problem is the following:

By: `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` you are disabling the jqm routing facility and so jqm does not listen on hash changes but the backbone router does. What you need to do is to define an event in your corresponding backbone view where the dialog shall be opened - would be something like:

```
var YourView = Backbone.View.extend({

[...]

events: {
   "click #myDialog: "openMyDialog"
},

openMyDialog:function() {
   [Call your Dialog/Popup here]
}


})
```